# How does one troubleshoot when a system hangs?

Tags: solaris

On Solaris 10, how do you generally troubleshoot when a system hangs. For example - when i run a command say metastat and hit enter, the system hangs. press control C it comes out and on again running metastat and enter the system hangs. Please let me know how to trouble shoot this and which logs I can check with examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Truss is a great command for quick troubleshooting, but Solaris has a decisive advantage for this type of work: [DTrace](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/dtrace_example.html). It will take some time to get fully up to speed with it, but never again will you need to wonder "what is it *doing?*"

Answer (score 0):

I would start with the [`truss`](http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Unix/Solaris/SOLARIS_UsingthetrussCommandinSolaris.shtml) command and the log files, you should monitor the follow files (thy record all system problems like disk errors, swap errors, NFS problems, etc):

```
tail -f /var/adm/SYSLOG
tail -f /var/adm/messages
tail -f /var/log/syslog
```

Comment: suppose I added a new patch to the sstem using patchadd command, after restart the system hangs... how can I troubleshoot such a situation. I have checked for all dependent patches and installed them already, but still the system hangs.

Comment: In that situation you would of course boot into single-user mode and start your analysis from there. And you can always boot from the CD and mount your root filesystem. It's very hard to make a modern Unix system totally unrecoverable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between when a command hangs and when a system hangs:

- if the system hangs all processes will hang
- if a command hangs only it is affected

What seems to be your case is a command hang, which can be troubleshot with `truss` - just run

```
truss -f command
```

and you'll see what it is doing and what system call it will hang on. The `-f` flag will tell `truss` to also follow child processes.

Since you mention that you are running `metastat` it is likely to be a disk issue, so looking for information about failed disks in `/var/adm/messages` would be a place to start.

Comment: does truss require root access ?

Comment: ‘truss‘ only require root access when you are trussing a setuid program